# Efficient way to concatenate Numpy arrays and extract indexes

Tags: python, numpy

I want to do the following:
1) Load 14 files into Numpy arrays
2) concatenate the 14 Numpy arrays
3) Extract the row indexes of where each Numpy array starts and ends according to the files in the concatenated array to create a new numpy array that assigns a class number from 1 to 14 to each row of data according to the file it belongs to.

I have created the following code to solve this:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt
from numpy import *


name1 = 'backandfforwwalk4smallstepsML'
name2 = 'backandfforwwalk4stepsML'
name3 = 'backandforsteps1lineML'
name4 = 'leftdnrightfarML'
name5 = 'sidestyletwoML'
name6 = 'walkingsideML'
name7 = 'fastwalkML'

class1 = genfromtxt('allSumRowSignals_'+ name1 + '_even.csv', delimiter=',')
class2 = genfromtxt('allSumRowSignals_'+ name1 + '_odd.csv', delimiter=',')
class3 = genfromtxt('allSumRowSignals_'+ name2 + '_even.csv', delimiter=',')
class4 = genfromtxt('allSumRowSignals_'+ name2 + '_odd.csv', delimiter=',')
class5 = genfromtxt('allSumRowSignals_'+ name3 + '_even.csv', delimiter=',')
class6 = genfromtxt('allSumRowSignals_'+ name3 + '_odd.csv', delimiter=',')
class7 = genfromtxt('allSumRowSignals_'+ name4 + '_even.csv', delimiter=',')
class8 = genfromtxt('allSumRowSignals_'+ name4 + '_odd.csv', delimiter=',')
class9 = genfromtxt('allSumRowSignals_'+ name5 + '_even.csv', delimiter=',')
class10 = genfromtxt('allSumRowSignals_'+ name5 + '_odd.csv', delimiter=',')
class11 = genfromtxt('allSumRowSignals_'+ name6 + '_even.csv', delimiter=',')
class12 = genfromtxt('allSumRowSignals_'+ name6 + '_odd.csv', delimiter=',')
class13 = genfromtxt('allSumRowSignals_'+ name7 + '_even.csv', delimiter=',')
class14 = genfromtxt('allSumRowSignals_'+ name7 + '_odd.csv', delimiter=',')


#Load files that have similar name


a = np.concatenate((class1,class2),axis=0)
b = np.concatenate((a,class3),axis=0)
c = np.concatenate((b,class4),axis=0)
d = np.concatenate((c,class5),axis=0)
e = np.concatenate((d,class6),axis=0)
f = np.concatenate((e,class7),axis=0)
g = np.concatenate((f,class8),axis=0)
h = np.concatenate((g,class9),axis=0)
i = np.concatenate((h,class10),axis=0)
j = np.concatenate((i,class11),axis=0)
k = np.concatenate((j,class12),axis=0)
l = np.concatenate((k,class13),axis=0)
m = np.concatenate((l,class14),axis=0)

#concatenate all of them, m is the concatenated file

#calculating the indexes for each class

class1ends = len(class1[:,1])
class2ends = len(a[:,1])
class3ends = len(b[:,1])
class4ends = len(c[:,1])
class5ends = len(d[:,1])
class6ends = len(e[:,1])
class7ends = len(f[:,1])
class8ends = len(g[:,1])
class9ends = len(h[:,1])
class10ends = len(i[:,1])
class11ends = len(j[:,1])
class12ends = len(k[:,1])
class13ends = len(l[:,1])
class14ends = len(m[:,1])

#is required to know in which row each of the files ends to assign a value number from 1 to 14 in a separate files, according to the number of files


Y = np.zeros((len(m)))

Y[0:class1ends+1]= 1
Y[class1ends:class2ends+1]= 2
Y[class2ends:class3ends+1]= 3
Y[class3ends:class4ends+1]= 4
Y[class4ends:class5ends+1]= 5
Y[class5ends:class6ends+1]= 6
Y[class6ends:class7ends+1]= 7
Y[class7ends:class8ends+1]= 8
Y[class8ends:class9ends+1]= 9
Y[class9ends:class10ends+1]= 10
Y[class10ends:class11ends+1]= 11
Y[class11ends:class12ends+1]= 12
Y[class12ends:class13ends+1]= 13
Y[class13ends:class14ends+1]= 14

#according to the previously saved indexes, creade a new variable with same length as m and assign a class number for each file


print class14ends

np.savetxt('y.csv', Y, delimiter=',', fmt="%s")
np.savetxt('X.csv', m, delimiter=',', fmt="%s")

#save classes as Y
#save data as X
```

I am looking for a faster, compacted and general way to do this (many files). Any recommendations?

Comment: Have you profiled this - is concatenation the slowest part of your code for sure?

Comment: on the issue of "compacted," use a `for` loop, dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can streamline this action by recognizing that `concatenate` takes a list of multiple arrays.

Here's a simpler example:

```
In [76]: class0=np.zeros((3,4))    
In [77]: class1=np.ones((2,4))
In [78]: class2=np.ones((5,4))*2
In [79]: class3=np.ones((2,4))*3
In [80]: class_list=[class0,class1,class2,class3]

In [81]: lenlist=[x.shape[0] for x in class_list]
In [82]: m = np.concatenate(class_list, axis=0)

In [84]: m
Out[84]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       ...
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.]])

In [85]: lenlist
Out[85]: [3, 2, 5, 2]
In [87]: class_ends=np.cumsum(lenlist)
In [88]: class_ends
Out[88]: array([ 3,  5, 10, 12], dtype=int32)

In [91]: Y=np.repeat(range(len(lenlist)),lenlist)
In [92]: Y
Out[92]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3])
```